# Where did my data get stuck in Ember? <!---->

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli-mirage

I'm trying to learn ember but having a hard time finding out why my data from the backend is not showing up. I'm using Ember Data with mirage fixtures. The data is showing up. Only if I introduce simple relationships the data from those relationships is not showing up in my app. Is there a general way how to debug when you just get `<!---->` in your ember app?

```js
mirage/fixtures/contacts.js

export default [
{
    id: 1,
    userName: "Barack Obama",
    profilePictureUrl: "/img/profilepics/barack.png",
    conversation: 1
},
];

mirage/fixtures/conversations.js

export default [
{
    id: 1,
    contact: 1,
    lastConversationTime: 'Sun Jun 07 2015 14:05:50 GMT+0200 (CEST)',
},
];


mirage/config.js

export default function() {

  this.get('/api/conversations');
  this.get('/api/conversations/:id');
  this.get('/api/contacts');
  this.get('/api/contacts/:id');

}
```

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
  this.route('contacts');
  this.route('conversations');
});

App.ContactsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('contact');
  }  
});

App.ConversationsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('conversation');
  }  
});


App.ContactModel = DS.Model.extend({
  userName: DS.attr('string'),
  profilePictureUrl: DS.attr('string'),
  conversation: DS.belongsTo('conversation'),
});

App.ConversationModel = DS.Model.extend({
  lastConversationTime: DS.attr('date'),
  contact: DS.belongsTo('contact')
});

$.mockjax({
  url: "/contacts",
  type: "GET",
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  responseText: {
    contacts: [{
    id: 1,
    userName: "Barack Obama",
    profilePictureUrl:"/img/profilepics/barack.png",
    conversation: 1
    }]
  }
  
});

$.mockjax({
  url: "/conversations",
  type: "GET",
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  responseText: {
    conversations: [{
    id: 1,
    contact: 1,
    lastConversationTime: 'Sun Jun 07 2015 14:05:50'
    }]
  }
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.11.1/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
  <script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.11.1/ember.debug.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ember-data.js/1.0.0-beta.16.1/ember-data.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mockjax/1.5.3/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
    
    {{link-to 'contacts' 'contacts'}}

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contacts">
    <ul>
      {{#each model as |contact|}}
        <li>{{contact.userName}}</li>
        <li>{{conversation.lastConversationTime}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ember: 1.12.1
Ember Data: 1.0.0-beta.19
jQuery: 1.11.3

This is a JSBin that reproduces the issue:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/deledemaya/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I'm not so sure what code I should post because I'm not even sure where to start looking for the mistake...

Comment: post your models and the json being sent down for each model.  Additionally post your versions.

Comment: Posted the model and the objects. I don't know how to get the json directly with mirrage but i guess the object thats logged in the console is as good as that.

Comment: The mocks from mirage will do

Comment: Also add the route, or if you are fetching the records a different way, show that code

Comment: The mirage mocks as well please :)

Comment: Added those as well. This is what I mean with I don't even know where to start looking for the problem. I'm wondering if there is a way how I can tell ok Mirage working.. Ok the data arrives in the store correctly.. And this way figuring out where the problem is. Its hard to google stuff when you don't even know where the problem is exactly.

Comment: Yeah, jumping in and using Ember Data adds a lot of complexity to Ember up front, it's got a decent learning curve, but then once you've even slightly crested it, it ruins trying to develop without it, personal opinion of course.

Comment: Sorry (I'm not familiar with mirage, so I'm having to read the documentation while I look through it all) can you show me the mirage config for contacts and conversations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79900/discussion-between-benedikt-and-kingpin2k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the JSBin example.

You've got a number of issues in your code.

First of all, in your template you're accessing the `conversation` model like this:

```
<ul>
  {{#each model as |contact|}}
    <li>{{contact.userName}}</li>
    <li>{{conversation.lastConversationTime}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

`conversation` is not defined anywhere. As `conversation` is a relationship on `contact`, you should access it via `contact` like this:

```
    <li>{{contact.conversation.lastConversationTime}}</li>
```

Note that you don't need a `conversation` route defined in order to access conversation via contact in the `contact` route.

Then, the convention is to name models as `App.Foo` and not `App.FooModel`. This info is useful only in JSBins, as modern Ember apps do not use globals (`App`).

Finally, your main mistake is that you defined your relationship as synchronous. Sync relationships assume that all requested related records are already available in the store. To achieve that, you have to sideload your related data like this:

```
$.mockjax({
  url: "/contacts",
  type: "GET",
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  responseText: {
    contacts: [{
      id: 1,
      userName: "Barack Obama",
      profilePictureUrl:"/img/profilepics/barack.png",
      conversation: 1
    }],
    conversations: [{
      id: 1,
      contact: 1,
      lastConversationTime: 'Sun Jun 07 2015 14:05:50'
    }]
  }
});
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/taboge/1/edit?html,js,output

Alternatively, you can define your relationship as async. This will tell Ember to retrieve records from the backend whenever it stumbles upon a missing relationship.

Example:

```
App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
  userName: DS.attr('string'),
  profilePictureUrl: DS.attr('string'),
  conversation: DS.belongsTo('conversation', {async: true}),
});

$.mockjax({
  url: "/contacts",
  type: "GET",
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  responseText: {
    contacts: [{
    id: 1,
    userName: "Barack Obama",
    profilePictureUrl:"/img/profilepics/barack.png",
    conversation: 1
    }]
  }

});

$.mockjax({
  url: "/conversations/1",
  type: "GET",
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK",
  responseText: {
    conversation: {
      id: 1,
      contact: 1,
      lastConversationTime: 'Sun Jun 07 2015 14:05:50'
    }
  }
});
```

Demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qejayi/1/edit?html,js,output

Async relationships force you to work with them via promises.

Also note that you don't have to define both directions of the relationship as async. In fact, you don't need the reverse relationship at all! You only need the reverse relationship if you want to obtain users for a given conversation.

And be warned that currently Ember is very eager on requesting asynchronously related records. If you only ask for an id of a related record, Ember will retrieve the whole record, even though wasn't necessary: the id was already known. I hope to see this problem resolved in one of upcoming Ember Data releases.

Comment: Perfect answer! Just note that your first JS Bin example is not working because its my original unmodified JsBin. But I understood the point anyways. Again thanks a lot!!!!